# Unity 2D - Freeze axis and AddForceAtPosition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision, rigid-bodies

I'm learning Unity 2D and I want to do something like this:
[image: example]

Basically the character runs into the box/edge and it falls over. BUT! I want to lock down the X axis somehow. So in reality it would kinda look like if it was just rotated simple by 90 degrees (with some kind of acceleration).

I've tried to do it with rigidbody2d and edgecollider and AddForceAtPosition, but I failed miserably.

What I really wanted to do is lock down the "wall" and apply the force at the very top of the rigidbody so it would just fall over to the right, but it simply didn't work out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked into [Hinge Joints](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-HingeJoint2D.html)?

Comment: Hmm, not yet! I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that same logic applies to physics in games as it does to physics in real life. Just make a hinge and put the anchor and connected anchor at the same location at the bottom and set a limit for hinge.

Wall:

[image]

Hinge:

[image]

I set Lower Angle to something near 90, otherwise wall becomes uneven when it drops.

Remember to put a Rigidbody2D and a Box Collider for wall.

Comment: It works well with Box Collider, is it possible to do it with Edge Collider as well? For some reason it just falls over right after I play the scene. ( [example](http://i.imgur.com/DfAjAF1.png) - obviously the edge collider transformed 90° at start)

Comment: @Andrew I haven't tested edge collider. If it falls, there is an uneven force on the object. Even here in my example if I move anchors to bottom left instead of bottom center, wall is going to fall to right when I play the scene because that's what's gonna happen in real life. If you have a problem with the direction, tweak the limit to 180 instead of 90.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would lock the rotational axes that you don't want to move on your rigidbody, then, if your object origin is located on the ground / bottom of the object, you can add rotational torque to the object to achieve the affect you want :) http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html